# Why does my redirect is not working?

Tags: javascript, salesforce

my script calls my redirect function to early, so the last file of a batch upload is failing. I have been search the whole morning an tried different approaches, but without success.

```
function uploadFile(something, callback) {



    var fileInput = $('#fileList1');
    //var reader = new FileReader();
    console.log(fileInput);
    if ( trim( fileInput.val() ).length == 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    var fileList = []; 
    count = fileInput[0].files.length; 
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){

        loadFile(fileInput[0].files[i]);

    }

    function loadFile(file){

        var reader = new FileReader(); 
        var fileName = getFileNameWithExtension( file);
        var file = file;
        while(reader.onprogress){
            console.log("reading");    
        }

        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var val = reader.result; 
            var text = val.split(',')[1];
            saveFile( fileName, text, parentId );
            if (!--count){
                redirect();                    
            }

        }

        reader.onerror = function(event) {
            console.error("File could not be read! Code " + reader.error.message);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    }

}
function redirect(){

    window.location.href = '/{!tempID}';
    return false;
}
```

Can someone give me a hint?

#

Hello, i have rewritten my methods a bit based on your suggestions. But the redirect is still called to early,...before all uploads are done.

```
function uploadFile() {


    var fileInput = $('#fileList1');

    console.log(fileInput);
    if ( trim( fileInput.val() ).length == 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    var countTwo = 0; 
    count = fileInput[0].files.length; 
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){

        loadFile(fileInput[0].files[i], function(val){
            console.log(val);
            if(val === 3){
                setTimeout(()=>{redirect();}, 5000);
            }

        });
    }

    function loadFile(file, callback){

        var reader = new FileReader(); 
        var fileName = getFileNameWithExtension( file);
        var file = file;
        while(reader.onprogress){
            console.log("reading");    
        }

        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var val = reader.result; 
            var text = val.split(',')[1];
            saveFile( fileName, text, parentId );
            console.log(" ct " + countTwo + " c " + count-1);
            countTwo++;

            if(!--count) callback(countTwo);

        }

        reader.onerror = function(event) {
            console.error("File could not be read! Code " + reader.error.message);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: (Recommended)

Detect when your uploading ends. And in that callback, call redirect.

Method 2:

```
// define your TIMEOUT first
setTimeout(()=>{redirect();}, TIMEOUT);
```

Comment: i had something like reader.onload = function(event) {
            var val = reader.result; 
            var text = val.split(',')[1];
            saveFile( fileName, text, parentId );
            if (!--count) callback();                    
            }

        }             but it didnt not work. Error was "callback is not a function"

Comment: @droidfish Where is your callback defined??

Comment: see above...there is a new version,..but still not working. How much files are uploaded is depending on the size of each file. I tried it with three, but just one was uploaded ( 0.5MB -> success, 2MB ->fail, 5MB-> fail)

Comment: @droidfish console.log your callback variable and see what it in fact is.

Comment: With three files ist this,...which looks ok... but stiil redirecting too fast    
    NaN VM76932 cs88.lightning.force.com&sfdcIFrameHost=web:129 
    NaN VM76932 cs88.lightning.force.com&sfdcIFrameHost=web:129 
    NaN VM76932 cs88.lightning.force.com&sfdcIFrameHost=web:108 
    3

Comment: i currently enden up calculating the timeout from filesize of all files         

            
            filesize = filesize + fileInput[0].files[i].size;
            loadFile(fileInput[0].files[i], function(val){
                console.log("val "+ val);
                console.log("size " + filesize/1024*2);
                if(val === fileInput[0].files.length){
                    setTimeout(()=>{redirect();}, filesize/1024*1.5);

Comment: can you give me an example for your method 1?

Comment: @droidfish You should detect when it is finished. Then I can tell you what to do in your callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
reader.onload = function(event) {
            var val = reader.result; 
            var text = val.split(',')[1];
            saveFile( fileName, text, parentId );
            if (!--count){
                setTimeout(()=>{redirect();}, 0);                    
            }

        }
```